# django The current path,didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

i want to try another apps in django but i got problem when access another apps.

[Page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLXhl.png)

tree:

main:

search:

- index.html
- scrape.html

preprocessing:

- index.html

the scenario like this. from scrape.html i want to access index.html in preprocessing but got an error path not found. I've done to add apps in settings.py

**main url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('search.urls')),
    path('preprocessing/', include('preprocessing.urls')),
]
```

**search url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,),
    path('scrape/',views.scrape,),
 
]
```

slice of scrape.html:

```
 <a href = "/preprocessing" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" target = "blank">Preprocessing</a>
```

**preprocessing url.py**

```
path('', views.index),
```

let me know where did I go wrong, thx for your help

Comment: Show your template. Also if you have set a value for `APPEND_SLASH` in the settings show that.

Comment: the problem may be in a trailing slash, try adding `/` at the end of the url where you call it (probably in `scrape.html`)

Comment: done, i've add slice my scrape.html to go /preprocessing and for my APPEND_SLASH = False @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: added for my scrape.html @ErsainD.

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag is written as:

```
<a href = "/preprocessing" ...>
```

The problem here is that your url pattern is like `'preprocessing/'`, notice that it ends in a trailing slash while your anchors url doesn't. Furthermore in your settings you set `APPEND_SLASH = False`.

Normally when Django finds a url not ending in a trailing slash it appends a slash to it and redirects the user to this new url. But you have stopped this behaviour by setting `APPEND_SLASH = False`. As the first step I would advice you to change this back to `APPEND_SLASH = True`.

Next you should always name your urls and use those names to refer to the urls. So your urlpatterns should be:

**main url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('search.urls')),
    path('preprocessing/', include('preprocessing.urls')),
]
```

**search url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('scrape/',views.scrape, name='scrape'),
 
]
```

**preprocessing url.py**

```
path('', views.index, name='preprocessing'),
```

Now in your templates you would simply use the [`url` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'preprocessing' %}" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" target = "blank">Preprocessing</a>
```

Comment: ittss workss, thanks a lot a sir for your help and your tips